# Is there a LINQ way to go from a list of key/value pairs to a dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a "LINQ" way to do this?

```
var array = new string[] { "BASE TABLE", "Table", "VIEW", "View" };
var list = array.ToList();
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i += 2)
{
    dictionary[list[i]] = list[i + 1];
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length / 2)
                       .ToDictionary(i => array[i * 2], i => array[i * 2 + 1]);
```

Answer (score 5):

As dtb points out, the aptly named "ToDictionary" method just might be what you're looking for.

If you intend for the dictionary to *never change* after its creation, and/or if you intend to have multiple values associated with a given key, then use the aptly named "ToLookup" method.

Comment: this was one of those things where my intuition told me there was probably a linq way, so I just wanted to know what it was.. I actually re-wrote my code to just create a dictionary and call Add() once for each pair - it seems simpler