# Convert List<string> to List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a LINQ way to go from a list of key/value pairs to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203928/is-there-a-linq-way-to-go-from-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-to-a-dictionary)

Assume that I have a `List<string>` as below:

```
var input = new List<string>()
                       {
                           "key1",
                           "value1",
                           "key2",
                           "value2",
                           "key3",
                           "value3",
                           "key4",
                           "value4"
                       };
```

Based on this list, I would like to convert to `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, the reason is to allow the same key, that's why I don't use Dictionary.

```
var output = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
                       {
                           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key1", "value1"),
                           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key2", "value2"),
                           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key3", "value3"),
                           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key4", "value4"),
                       };
```

I can achieve by using below code:

```
var keys = new List<string>();
var values = new List<string>();

for (int index = 0; index < input.Count; index++)
{
    if (index % 2 == 0) keys.Add(input[index]);
    else values.Add(input[index]);
}

var result = keys.Zip(values, (key, value) => 
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value));
```

But feeling that this is not the best way using loop `for`, is there any another way that we can use built-in LINQ to achieve it?

Comment: "LINQ rule #1": Unless you are able to come with LINQ query yourself in 3 minutes, it is not worth using it. Use simple for loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var output = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Count / 2)
                       .Select(i => Tuple.Create(input[i * 2], input[i * 2 + 1]))
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Do this `var output = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Count / 2).Select
(i => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(input[i * 2], input[i * 2 + 1])).ToList();` since OP needs a KeyValuePair

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't suggest using LINQ here as there is really no reason to and you don't gain anything by using LINQ, but simply using a normal `for` loop and increasing your counting variable by two in each iteration:

```
var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

for (int index = 1; index < input.Count; index += 2)
{
    result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(input[index - 1], input[index]));
}
```

Note that I'm starting my index with `1` so I don't run into an exception for accessing an invalid index in case the number of items in `input` is odd, i.e. if `input` ends with a "half pair" of values.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list = 
        input.Where((s, i) => i % 2 == 0)
             .Select((s, i) => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s, input.ElementAt(i * 2 + 1)));
```

Comment: That's also good Linq :)

Comment: Glad to here that, though myself feeling to be too similar to the answer, ooops)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ Aggregate() function (the code is longer than a simple loop):

```
var result = 
input.Aggregate(new List<List<string>>(),
                (acc, s) =>
                {
                    if (acc.Count == 0 || acc[acc.Count - 1].Count == 2)
                        acc.Add(new List<string>(2) { s });
                    else
                        acc[acc.Count - 1].Add(s);
                    return acc;
                })
                .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x[0], x[1]))
                .ToList();
```

N.B.
this works even if your initial input becomes a generic `IEnumerable<string>` and not specifically a `List<string>`