# Split into KeyValuePair instead of Array

Tags: linq, keyvaluepair

I have a string of data:

```
Key1=Value1,Key2=Value2,KeyN=ValueN
```

I'm trying to split the string into

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
```

I can easily do this:

```
List<string[]> values = item.Split( ',' ).Select( p => p.Split( '=' ) ).ToList();
```

but I just can't figure out the way to get that into the List of KeyValuePair's.  The closest I've gotten so far is:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values = item.Split( ',' )
.Select( p => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(){ p.Split( '=' ) } ).ToList();
```

But that's still a bit off :(

I know I can easily do it with a loop but I'd really like to get it working in Linq as practice makes perfect.  I've seen quite a few examples already of similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981936/convert-liststring-to-listkeyvaluepairstring-string-using-linq), but I can't seem to join the dots between those questions and mine so please forgive me if I've accidentally posted a duplicate.

Any help would really be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've done so far is good. Then, you have two ways to achieve what you want:

### Create a method `ToKeyValuePair`

```
public static KeyValuePair<string, string> ToKeyValuePair(string[] array)
{
    if (array.Length != 2)
        throw new ArgumentException("The array must contain exactly 2 elements.");

    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(array[0], array[1]);
}

var values = (item.Split( ',' )
                  .Select( p => ToKeyValuePair(p.Split( '=' ))))
                  .ToList();
```

### Use the LINQ query syntax

If I convert the above line into query syntax:

```
var values = (from p in item.Split( ',' )
              select ToKeyValuePair(p.Split( '=' )))
             .ToList();
```

Not much has changed.

But, thanks to this new syntax, it is quite easy to remove the usage of `ToKeyValuePair(...)` thanks to the `let` clause:

```
var values = (from p in item.Split( ',' )
              let splittedP = p.Split( '=' )  // Declares a variable
              select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(splittedP[0], splittedP[1]))
             .ToList();
```

Of course, the last line can be written with Extention methods syntax (ie with `.Select(p=>...)`), but is hard to read:

```
var values = (item.Split(',')
                  .Select(p => new { p, splittedP = p.Split('=') })
                  .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(p.splittedP[0], p.splittedP[1])))
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Cedric, thanks soooo much for a). the prompt reply and b). the level of detail you went to in explaining, I really appreciate it. I'm trying it out at the moment and I'll get back to you in a sec :)

Comment: I tried out the 2nd Linq one, but I'm getting Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>

Comment: That last one is magic, I see now where I went wrong, such Homer moment, tried to join them together instead of do them separate, thanks Cedric ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I stumbled across it on google. I solved the problem using the accepted answer but a shortened it a little. You don't need the `new { p, splittedP = p.Split('=') }` part, just `p.Split('=')`

```
var values = data.Split(',').Select(p=>p.Split('='))
              .Select(s => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s[0], s[1]))
              .ToList();
```

You could also do something like this if your keys are unique:

```
var values = data.Split(',').Select(p => p.Split('='))
              .ToDictionary(k => k[0], v => v[1]);
```

Which is much shorter and basically gets you a list with with O(1) access.

(This is with .NET 4.5)

Answer (score 0):

use above code. must trim the key.

```
public static string GetUserInfo(this X509Certificate2 x509,X509Oid oid)
{
      try
      {
           var kvs = x509.Subject.Split(',').Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Split('=')[0].Trim(), x.Split('=')[1].Trim())).ToList();

           string value = kvs.FirstOrDefault(A => A.Key == oid.ToString()).Value;
           return value;
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {   
       }
       return "";
}
```

Add an enum file.

```
public enum X509Oid
{
        O,
        E,
        L,
        C,
        S,
        G,
        SN,
        CN,
        Street
}
```